# WCF DataMember shows default namespace when DataContract namespace has been declared

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0

Just wanted to thank the community first off for previous help. I have a new question about default namespace in WCF. I have explicitly set a namespace for my DataContract as such:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.mydomain.com")]
```

One of my DataMembers under the DataContract is a class derived from a reference in my project

```
[DataMember]
public MyClass MyClassName
```

My issue is that I get the default namespace for this DataMember:

```
http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyClass
```

and I would like it to fall under the namespace of the DataContract. How can I change this

Comment: One more note. I have also tried overriding the ContractNamespace as below and still have same issue: `code`[assembly:ContractNamespace("http://www.mydomain.com,ClrNamespace = "MyDomain")] `code`